# Why my form data are not intercepted in my mainController in Java Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I get an Internal Server Error, status=500: java.lang.NumberFormatException
The reason seems to be that my form data,  sent via name attribute is not intercepted by @RequestMapping or HttpServletRequest doesn't work..

Here I try to pass the data:

```
<form action="/tankbeurt" method="get"  style="padding: 5px;">
    <div style="padding: 10px;">
        <label for="huidig">Huidige kilometerstand</label>
        <input type="text" name="huidig" id="huidig"></div>
    <div style="padding: 10px;">
      <label  for="vorig">Vorige kilometerstand</label>
      <input type="text" name="vorig" id="vorig"></div>
    <div style="padding: 10px;">
      <label  for="liter">Hoeveel liter heb je bijgetankt</label>
      <input type="text" name="liter" id="liter"></div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Bereken Verbruik"></div>
```

And I try to intercept it in the mainController:

```
@Controller
public class MainController {
    @RequestMapping("/tankbeurt")
    public String gegevens(HttpServletRequest request, Model model){

        int huidigeKm =  Integer.parseInt("huidig");
        System.out.println(huidigeKm);
        int vorigeKm=  Integer.parseInt("vorig");
        double liter=  Double.parseDouble("liter");
        Tankbeurt tankinformatie = new Tankbeurt(vorigeKm,huidigeKm,liter);
        model.addAttribute("informatieTanken",tankinformatie);
        return "tankbeurt";
}
```

Thankyou for your help. I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Integer.parseInt("huidig");
```

You are trying to parse string "huidig" to integer. That's the cause of exception. Try looking for some method that extracts property from the model, like "model.getAttribute("huidig")".

Comment: Thankyou very much! I did oversee it! How could I not see it :-)